# Gmail REST api does not allow text/calendar in an email's multipart/alternative mime

Tags: gmail-api

Background:
You have an email mime that has this structure -

```
_multipart/mixed______________________
|   |_ multipart/alternative                
|   |   |_ content-type: text/plain      
|   |   |_ content-type: text/html        
|   |   |_ content-type: text/calendar
|   | 
|   |_ content-type: application/ics : Here the same ics file is added as
|                                      an attachment with base64 encoding.
|_______________________________________
```

**The above mime is same as google calendar's event invitation email.**

**Problem**: 
Now, if you try sending this mime programatically via GMAIL's REST api, then on the recipient's end, the mime received does not have the text/calendar part in it. As a result of this issue, the recipient's client will not be able show special event action buttons (yes, no & maybe).

**Few Observations**:
1) If you check the mime of the same email from your sent folder, then you will get the text/calendar part in it.

2) If you do this whole experiment (having the same mime) via google's SMTP protocol, then everything will work fine.

**What steps will reproduce the problem?** 
1) Create a google calendar event from account A and invite account B 
       1.1) Send the invitation email to B 
2) Open B's email account and check for the invitation email 
       2.1) Download the invite.ics attachment from it. 
3) Now, try composing programatically an email with the same mime structure that B got from google and use the above invite.ics. 
4) Try sending it from A's account to B via REST api.

At B's side, if you open the email ("show original" part), then the text/calendar will be missing now. Now, if you do the same thing via SMTP, then you will not face this issue.

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?** 
**Expected**: The mime should have been intact and should have the text/calendar part in it. 
**Reality**: The text/calendar part was missing.

Comment: Refer [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758842) thread for progress from Gmail Team on this issue. So, far, they have accepted the issue and have added to their internal issue tracking system.